# Toshiba Laptop screen size

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display

I am a web developer, and I have been developing a website. But while developing the website, I looked at my website from another computer, and the website looked different from laptop to laptop (In terms of zoom). I have found this problem across all of the websites I visit. I will usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> these websites to make them visible. I can't do that with the new website. I tried <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>, I tried the zoom when you go to `Windows --> Control Panel` to adjust screen resolution. I tried the `System --> Display` slider. I am just at a loss for what to do.

This is an image of my settings:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui6NO.png]

Comment: Are the laptops the same resolution? In your browser you can reset the view with `ctrl` + `0` or `ctrl` + `end`. You can also try [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com) to simulate different browsers and screen sizes.

Comment: I set this laptop to every resolution and it did not change anything(In terms of website view)

Comment: How about operating system and browser. I know for sure (from own experience) that websites look different on the same machine when switchen from Windows to Linux and also when switching between browsers.

Comment: Both computers were win10 and both in chrome where they were developed